# How to prevent my computer to connect to certain IPs?

Tags: windows, ip, blocking

What is the best way to prevent my Windows computer to access certain IPs?

So far, I did it by adding this kind of lines to my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1       219.141.147.70
```

However that doesn't seem like a clean solution since instead of going to 219.141.147.70, the computer connects to 127.0.0.1. Is there any way to completely block 219.141.147.70 so that when the computer tries to connect to it, the connection is really blocked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can block that ip on Windows Firewall Advanced Settings

Create a new outgoing rule and choose block all

I can't take screenshot now but you can read details in technet page : http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff602926%28WS.10%29.aspx on "Configuring a profile" section.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to configure the machine's firewall to prevent those access.